# Is it possible to automate setting of Artifactory properties?

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory seems to automatically generate properties for RPMs, Python wheels etc. Can I extend this function for my own file formats?

I've read the documentation and this talks about the REST API etc but I want to have Artifactory pull properties straight out of the file that I'm uploading.

None yet - I'm asking how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic that automatically generates properties for RPMs etc is hardcoded into each package type Artifactory supports, and you can't add custom repository types.

What you *can* do is write a [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) which runs whenever a file is uploaded, reads the file, and adds the appropriate properties. For example:

```
storage {
    afterCreate { item ->
        if (!item.isFolder() && item.name.endsWith(".customext")) {
            def fstream = repositories.getContent(item.repoPath).inputStream
            // read fstream and generate properties
            repositories.setProperty(item.repoPath, propName, propVal)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some notes:

- The language is Groovy. If you aren't familiar with Groovy, in a pinch you can pretend it's Java, since most Java is also valid Groovy.
- User plugin documentation is [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins)
- User plugin API Javadoc is [here](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html)
- For reference, the officially supported plugins are all [here](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins)